# How to reset a form AFTER its submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

The following code runs when the user submits the form. After a check on the quantity of forms submitted (the user can only submit 5 times), the form is recorded on the server side in a google sheet.

```
function validateForm(form){   
    if(count>=MAX){
        var msg={
            title:"Idea limit reached",
            body:"You can propose a maximum of "+MAX+" ideas for this theme",
            btn:"OK"
        }
        screenMessage(msg)
    }
    else{
        var msg={
            title:"Idea recorded",
            body:"You can still submit "+(5-count-1)+" ideas",
            btn:"OK"
        }
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successMessage(msg), resetForm()).recordIdea(form)    
        count++
    }
    return false;  
  }
function resetForm(){
    $('#title').val("")
    $('#description').val("")
    $('input[name="tags"]').val("")
    $('.creation-tags').empty()
    $('.suggested-tags').empty();
}
```

My problem is that when I check the database, the information i typed are empty! Meaning the "resetForm" function is actually called BEFORE the form submission.

Is there a way to ensure the resetForm function is called only after the values typed by the user have been successfully submitted ?

I tried to nest the function in the successMessage function with no positive result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is calling resetForm() right away, not setting the callback function:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successMessage(msg), resetForm()).recordIdea(form)
```

It should look like this:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){successMessage(msg), resetForm()}).recordIdea(form)
```

Comment: Long story short to try to explain this better, you need a "callback function" in "withSuccessHandler".  Instead, what your code is doing is basically injecting the return value of "successMessage" and "resetForm", because those are being run as soon as Javascript encounters them.  You can find all sorts of articles and posts about callback functions if you need a better understanding of them.